# When should I NOT call GC.SuppressFinalize(this) in Dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, finalizer

I have a simple class like this that implements `IDisposable` and so it's hit by a [CA1816: Call GC.SuppressFinalize correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1816):

```cs
public class A : IDisposable
{
    // ...
    int foo

    public A()
    {
        SomeObj.SomeEvent += DoSomething;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SomeObj.SomeEvent -= DoSomething;
    }
}
```

> Change A.Dispose() to call GC.SuppressFinalize(object). This will prevent derived types that introduce a finalizer from needing to re-implement 'IDisposable' to call it.

Now I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038571/whats-the-purpose-of-gc-suppressfinalizethis-in-dispose-method), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621152/should-gc-suppressfinalize-be-called-on-objects-that-do-not-have-a-finalizer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/when-should-i-use-gc-suppressfinalize?rq=3) but I still do not understand exactly what that is for (more explanation below). So **my questions are**:

- Should I always just add `GC.SuppressFinalize(object)` into my `Dispose` method if I do not understand what it is?
- When should I **NOT** do this and just suppress the warning?

---

To add more context: I still do not understand what `SuppressFinalize` is doing. I know I already disposed **some** resources in `Dispose` (event handlers in the example, or `IDisposable` resources etc) but what about the variables like `int foo` that still need to be cleaned up? And what about the warning part of "This will prevent derived types that introduce a finalizer from needing to re-implement"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use GC.SuppressFinalize()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151051/when-should-i-use-gc-suppressfinalize)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I already linked that one in my question. It answers _when_, but I still do not understand what it does, so my question focuses more on _when not_, to make sure I am not using it wrongly.

Comment: So you did - I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: The finalizer cleans up the object. The `Dispose` method generally does the same clean-up work. If there is something that will be done in the finalizer that is not done in the `Dispose` method then you should not suppress the finalizer. Such a situation should almost never arise, so you should almost always suppress the finalizer. I can't even think of a scenario that would require finalization after disposal but I suspect that you'd know it if you encountered one.

Comment: I usually disable CA1816 because if you declare a finalizer in my codebases, that's twenty lashes.

Comment: So to clarify what I read, this is only useful **if** I have an explicit deconstructor (`~A`)? Partly I am confused because I have no such thing in my class and still receive the warning. I thought what it is suppressed would be the cleaning of **all** other resources (like my variables etc).

Comment: Why did you enable this analysis?

Comment: @shingo it's enabled by default. I never enabled it.

Comment: To know more about what happens when the finalizers does its job, take a look at: https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers) or destructor is a legacy of C++, but in C# it extends the time the GC takes for objects to be collected.

> Unnecessary finalizers, including empty finalizers, finalizers that only call the base class finalizer, or finalizers that only call conditionally emitted methods, cause a needless loss of performance.

When you use the dispose pattern, you manually release (or by the using statement) resources, finalizers are no longer needed. The method `GC.SuppressFinalize` is to tell GC to ignore the finalizer of the target and collect it like a regular object, thereby improving the performance of GC. If you don't call this method, you lose the meaning of using the dispose pattern, so it's a good practice to always add it.

> Partly I am confused because I have no such thing in my class and still receive the warning.

Yes, your class does not have a finalizer, but you cannot guarantee that its subclasses do not either. Note that this analysis will not be reported in sealed classes (according to my testing, internal/private classes will also not).

> When should I NOT do this and just suppress the warning?

It should be never. As mentioned above, even if you don't call `GC.SuppressFinalize`, it usually only affects performance. Unless you release resources in the dispose method and in the finalizer separately, but it feels like this is some kind of programming mistake.

Comment: Ah, so I should call them in case a subclass does have it. Could you add answer to my main concern: is there any case where I should NOT use it? I assume what I can get from this answer is, always add `GC.SuppressFinalize` if I do not know any special use case?

Comment: You'd better follow [the dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern), actually VS could generate it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have read that pattern before but didn't really understand what is going on there. Maybe I will give it another try later.